# Class with constructor that strips a text file and moves elements to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class, text-files

I am given a text file and told that I have to create a class that catalogues all the countries in it. Although when I try to print statements to test if the code is working, it returns nothing. There are no syntax errors, it is just a logic error. If anyone could advise what to do that would be amazing.

My code looks like:

```
class CountryCatalogue:
    def __init__(self, countryFile):
        self._countryCat = []
        self._countryFile = open(countryFile, "r", encoding="utf-8")
        self._countryLines = self._countryFile.readlines()
        for line in self._countryLines[1:]:
            line = line.strip(',')
            data = line.split("|")
            newCountry = Country(data[0], data[2], data[3], data[1])
            self._countryCat.append(newCountry)
```

An example of the text file is:

```
Country|Continent|Population|Area
Brazil|South America|193,364,000|8,511,965
Canada|North America|34,207,000|9,976,140
China|Asia|1,339,190,000|9,596,960
```

An Example of my country class is:

```
class Country:
    def __init__(self,name,population,area,continent):
        self._name= name
        self._population = population
        self._area = area
        self._continent = continent
```

Comment: There's not obviously wrong (to me) in your code that would explain the results you say you're getting. You need to provide a [mre] that illustrates the problem — which means you will need to include a definition of the `Country` class being used as well as add code that actually makes use of your `CountryCatalogue` class.

Comment: you aren't showing the calling code.